# start IntentService from onDestroy() of activity

Tags: android, parse-platform, intentservice, ondestroy

Basically, i am implementing ONLINE and OFFLINE FEATURE in my app with  parse...so when user starts the app his status goes to online but how to know when he is offline except of logout...if the user kill the app...that's is why i am asking this question...

I want to send a json to my server with intent service on activity  onDestroy() method but that intent service is not fired on activity onDestroy() method..Or how can i detect the application kill

I had made my every effort but no results found on web even on stackverflow.

So any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: What you doing is ok i think so. But if that activity in not in foreground or in background then `onDestroy()` would not be callled.

Comment: everything about detection of application kill was already asked ... please, use google search

Comment: I already had searched the web guys...i am stuck here for more than a day...

Comment: @Selvin, i already had searched the web, if you know please provide me the link

Comment: @Clairvoyant,  how can i detect it..please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect when an Application gets killed, you must save your data proactively.

Besides, it makes no sense to try to start a Service to perform a long-running task while your application gets killed, if it worked it would mean that your application would never get killed.

Try to save your data as soon as possible, in the worst case in `Activity.onStop()`.

Comment: thanks Bladecode, i know this but i want to implement ONLINE and OFFLINE FEATURE in my app with  parse...so when user starts the app his status goes to online but how to know when he is offline except of logout...if the user kill the app...that's is why i am asking this question....i don't have any other alternate

Comment: You can determine if the user is outside of the app after the last active Activity calls onStop(). You need to override onStart() and onStop() in all your Activities to be able to determine that. You can create a BaseActivity to make this easier.